# How do I grep last match in a range of files?

Tags: grep

I have files named `memOutput.X` where `X` ranges from 0 to 47 in a directory. I want to see the line with the last occurrence of `VmData` in all these files. I can run

```
grep VmData memOutput.0 | tail -1
```

to get the last match from one file but not sure how to do it for a range of files. Also, `grep VmData memOutput.* | tail -1` displayed only the last match from file `memOutput.47`. Is there an alternative to `grep`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop?

```
for file in memOutput.*; do
    grep -H VmData "${file}" | tail -n 1
done
```

Or if you want a one-liner:

```
for file in memOutput.*; do grep -H VmData "${file}" | tail -n 1;done
```

Comment: It will work, but is there a one-liner way to do it?

Comment: for file in memOutput.*; do grep -H VmData "${file}" | tail -n 1;done